# should I use bytes or string in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

It seems like in OCaml, bytes and string are pretty much the same, except that bytes is mutable and string is immutable. Does it mean that everywhere I use bytearrays, but are not interested in mutability, I should use string?

Comment: there is no response on that question

Comment: That question was closed. If you disagree with the close reason, you can edit the question to better convey your intentions, and it'll get added to the reopen queue to be reviewed. But asking the same question again separately is just a blatant attempt to get around the rules.

Comment: No it's not. I removed the "opinion" part, as per the guidance, and reposted the question, as per the guidance (that said "repost or edit")

Comment: You've removed your own opinion, which was pretty bad taste but not necessarily against the rules. You're still _asking_ for opinion, however, which is against the rules. See [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: How is this asking for an opinion? Aren't there best practices to write safe code in OCaml?

Comment: "Best practices" are just opinion touted by some perceived authority. And any question as broad as "should I use X or Y" can only be answered with opinion.

Comment: I would disagree, but I guess the community doesn't take security seriously

Comment: This has nothing to do with security and whether it's taken seriously, and everything to do with SO not being a forum that's suitable for discussing opinion. As you have thoroughly demonstrated so far.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a reasonable rule of thumb. The purpose of introducing bytes was to allow strings to be immutable. Strings were mutable in older OCaml versions. But immutable strings are a lot nicer if you don't want to modify them.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use string, unless you can't.

Here is the simple reasoning:

1. If you try to modify a string that you didn't intent to modify the compiler will tell you and fail.
2. If you modify bytes that you didn't intent to modify then you have no idea what the code will do with that.

Only one of these options will tell you what is wrong at compile time.

If you modify a string and you intended to do that then you change it to bytes and compile again. But if you have a bytes and end up never modifying it nothing will remind you that you could have used string instead.